# JavaScript regex does opposite of what's expected

Tags: javascript

I have a regex that's doing the opposite of what's expected... I have something that could either be a number or not. I tried using isNaN but it gave odd results, so I thought I'd try a regex. That is giving even weirder results. The html looks like
`<span class="label">31</span>`
and I grab it via `var text = document.querySelectorAll('.label, .content');`

Then I process it via:

```
for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
 if (text[i].innerText.search(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
  // do number stuff
 }
}
```

but it matches everything that's not a number and doesn't process the numbers. If I change the regex to `/^[^0-9]+$/` (the negating character) it does match on the numbers. This is the opposite of what I would expect! Anybody have an idea what might be going on?

Thanks.

Comment: `search` returns an index or `-1` if not found. Maybe you want `test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`search` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) works like `indexOf` and returns the index where the regex has been found, or `-1` if it was not found. As your regex would only match at position 0, it returns only that or `-1` - and while `-1` is a truthy value, `0` is not. That's why the behaviour is "inverted".

You could do

```
if (text[i].innerText.search(/^[0-9]+$/) == 0)
```

but you'd better use the [`test` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) of the regex object which returns the boolean that you want:

```
if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(text[i].innerText))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use search, use match.

```js
var text = document.querySelectorAll('.label');

if( text[0].innerText.match(/^[0-9]+$/) ){
 console.log("Has numbers")
}else{
 console.log("No numbers")
}
```

```html
<span class="label">31</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're going to do is check for the presence of a match, use `test`:

```
if(/^[0-9]+$/.test(text[0].innerText)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove that "^" and try. because "^" requests to select items that doesn't match the regex expression.
so it should be /[0-9]+$/ not /^[0-9]+$/.

Comment: When used outside the [] the carrot symbol means "beginning"; only inside the [] is it the "negation" character.